# transpose graph

Tags: java, graph

how can I write a program in java to find the transpose of the graph G, where the input and the output of the program are represented as adjacency list structure.
for example:

> input:   1>2>3>4>1
>
> output:   1>4>3>2>

Comment: is this homework? if yes, tag it.

Comment: Why did you feel the need to put the entire flipping thing in **bold**? Do you see other people doing that?

Answer (score 5):

Let's say given a graph `G`, and a vertex `V` in `Vertices(G)`, `G[V]` is the adjacency list of `V`.

In pseudocode:

```
FUNCTION transpose(Graph G) : Graph
   INIT Graph GT

   FOR EVERY Vertex U IN Vertices(G) DO
      FOR EVERY Vertex V IN G[U] DO
          append(GT[V], U)

   RETURN GT
```

This is `O(|V|+|E|)`.

---

#### Java implementation

The following implementation closely follows the pseudocode. The only thing added is the `null` check for `append`. Vertex labels are `String`, and a graph is represented as a `Map<String,List<String>>`

```
import java.util.*;
public class Transpose {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,List<String>> g = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
        g.put("A", Arrays.asList("B", "C"));
        g.put("B", Arrays.asList("A", "D"));
        g.put("C", Arrays.asList("D"));

        System.out.println(g);
        // prints "{A=[B, C], B=[A, D], C=[D]}"
        //
        // .--- A <--> B --> D <--.
        // |                      |
        // '---------> C ---------'

        Map<String,List<String>> gT = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
        for (String u : g.keySet()) {
            for (String v : g.get(u)) {
                List<String> gTv = gT.get(v);
                if (gTv == null) {
                    gT.put(v, gTv = new ArrayList<String>());
                }
                gTv.add(u);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(gT);
        // prints "{D=[B, C], A=[B], B=[A], C=[A]}"
        //
        // .--> A <--> B <-- D ---.
        // |                      |
        // '---------- C <--------'     
    }
}
```

**Caveat**: this core algorithm doesn't keep vertices with neither in-bound nor out-bound edge(s), but that requires only a trivial processing.

Answer (score 0):

public Graph getTransposedGraph() {

```
    List<Vertex> transposedVertexList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Vertex v : this.vertexList) {
        transposedVertexList.add(v);
    }
    for (Edge e : this.edgeList) {
        transposedVertexList.get(transposedVertexList.indexOf(e.getTargetVertex()))
                .addNeighbour(e.getSourceVertex()); //Swap the vertexes of edge by making source as neighbour of Target vertex 
    }
    Graph transposedGraph = new Graph(transposedVertexList, edgeList);

    return transposedGraph;
}
```